# Casting a reference vs using new (ArrayList)

Tags: java, casting, object-oriented-analysis

I have a method that returns a List. (getListMethod)

Is there functional difference between?

```
ArrayList myList = (ArrayList) getListMethod();
```

and

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(getListMethod());
```

Comment: Of course there is. One is creating a new object, the other is assigning a reference to an existing object. This might fail if the object is not of type `ArrayList`.

Comment: The other big difference is that the second one won't compile.  (Unless there happens to be a variable named `getListMethod`...)  You're missing a `()`.

Comment: ajb good catch, fixed.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis actually, it will fail when object is not of class ArrayList or it subclass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

```
ArrayList myList = (ArrayList) getListMethod();
```

creates a new reference to the same `ArrayList`, while

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(getListMethod());
```

copies the elements of the old list to a new one.

I am assuming here that you know that `getListMethod()` really returns an `ArrayList`, otherwise you might run into other problems with the first variant as well.

Comment: Yes I do know, but I feel like that's a bad thing.  I'm guessing it is better to act as if I do not know, in case the internal implementation of getListMethod change and users a different type of List?

Comment: @user2484014: Yes, exactly. A good approach is otherwise to use `List myList = getListMethod()`, unless you really need an `ArrrayList`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Marking this as the answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me.  Yes I think it's required.  I'm putting the list into a Bundle (Android) as a ParceableArrayList.